# error in update table

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

when i try to update a table the app crashing and return this fatal error:

```
06-09 08:02:34.026: I/Database(342): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such column: username
06-09 08:02:34.034: E/Database(342): Error updating valore=1234 using UPDATE parametri SET valore=? WHERE _parametro=username
06-09 08:02:34.034: D/AndroidRuntime(342): Shutting down VM
06-09 08:02:34.034: W/dalvikvm(342): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
06-09 08:02:34.054: E/AndroidRuntime(342): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-09 08:02:34.054: E/AndroidRuntime(342): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: username: , while compiling: UPDATE parametri SET valore=? WHERE _parametro=username
```

The function of insert/update is this:

```
    String strFilter = ParametriMetaData.PARAMETRO+"=" + parametro;
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put(ParametriMetaData.VALORE, valore);

    System.out.println( strFilter );

    mDb.update(ParametriMetaData.TAB_PARAMETRI, args, strFilter, null);
```

This is the definition of table:

```
private static final String CREA_TAB_PARAMETRI = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "  //codice sql di creazione della tabella
                    + ParametriMetaData.TAB_PARAMETRI + " ("
                    + ParametriMetaData.PARAMETRO+ " text primary key, "
                    + ParametriMetaData.VALORE + " text not null);";
```

Whatsup? Thank you!

Comment: Table structure properly please. Can't tell what ParametriMetaData.TAB_PARAMETRI etc. are..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update query must have proper where clause  `update(tablename, value, referenceField+"=?", value);`

```
String strFilter = ParametriMetaData.PARAMETRO+"=?";
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put(ParametriMetaData.VALORE, valore);

    System.out.println( strFilter );

    mDb.update(ParametriMetaData.TAB_PARAMETRI, args, strFilter, parametro);
```

Comment: The error msg says that column "username" does not exist.  Are you sure the query is malformed?

Answer (score 0):

I would go to sqlite3 (via adb shell) and verify that the table in question has a column named "username".  You can see the SQL CREATE statement with `schema ?TABLE?`.  I think you will there is a problem with the table structure.

You access the `sqlite3` command by executing `adb shell` in a terminal(unix) or command prompt(windows) and then `sqlite3`.  [The documentation for sqlite3 can be found here.](http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html)